# Azure Pipeline for Xamarin Forms iOS Fails at Nuget Restore

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-devops, mono, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have searched everywhere all day long trying to get this pipeline to work.

It starts the pipeline and my tasks seem to run fine right up until I hit nuget restore for my solution. It fails with:

```
Unable to locate executable file: 'mono'
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I am using the macOS-latest vm image and I am using this task to set the mono version:

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      SYMLINK=6_8_0_123
      MONOPREFIX=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/$SYMLINK
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH;]$MONOPREFIX/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PKG_CONFIG_PATH;]$MONOPREFIX/lib/pkgconfig:$MONOPREFIX/share/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]$MONOPREFIX/bin:$PATH"
```

Is there something else I can set to make Nuget find the mono library?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems NuGet task hasn't been implemented to work on that agent, how about use the .NET Core (dotnet restore) task instead of nuget restore task?

Comment: This did turn out to be the solution for this error message, but just brought an onslaught of other errors in my process. I tried a number of combinations of dotnet restore and nuget restore for specific projects as it seems that dotnet restore didn't restore xamarin ios library projects which caused build failures. In the end running runNugetRestore in the xamarin ios build task was what worked.

Comment: I am glad to hear that you have resolved this issue. I have convert the comments to the answer with your content. You could check if you have any modifications and additions, please modify my answer directly for free. BTW,  you could accept it as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure Pipeline for Xamarin Forms iOS Fails at Nuget Restore

According to the error message:

```
Unable to locate executable file: 'mono'
```

It seems the NuGet task hasn't been implemented to work on that agent (`macOS-latest`) at this moment.

To resolve above error, we could use the `.NET Core (dotnet restore)` task instead of nuget restore task.

The final solution for this specific case:

Thanks to jmichas for sharing. Use the `.NET Core (dotnet restore)` task indeed resolve that error. But, it brought an onslaught of other errors in specific case. The final solution for this specific case is that use the `runNugetRestore` in the xamarin ios build task:

```
- task: XamariniOS@2
  inputs:
     runNugetRestore: true
```

Hope this helps others.